# pass access_token to charge function from callback function

Tags: python, flask, stripe-payments

So I'm trying to get Stripe Connect to work with flask using this example:

https://gist.github.com/amfeng/3517668

Issue I am having: How do I pass the access_token from

```
@app.route('/oauth/callback', methods=['GET','POST'])
def callback():
```

to another function in a different view like for example:

```
@app.route('/charge', methods=['POST'])
def charge():
```

Its the one thing I can't remember how to do. Pass a local variable to another function.

Sorry, its a dumb question, I know. I just can't figure it out in this case.

Thanks.

Comment: Upvoted for giving me the link to that gist! thx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you will want to do is *store* the access token somewhere so that later you can load and use it.  The simplest and most *insecure* place you can store it is the session:

```
@app.route("/oauth/callback")
def callback():
    # retrieve access_token
    session["stripe_token"] = access_token
    return redirect(to_somewhere_that_makes_sense)
```

Then, when you need the token, you can look it up:

```
@app.route('/charge', methods=['POST'])
def charge():
    access_token = session.get("stripe_token")
    if not access_token:
        raise MyMissingAccessTokenException()
        # Or whatever you want to do here

    # User has an access token - try to use it here
```

Now the session is serialized and sent over to the client in a cookie, so it is *not* a secure way to pass around data like an access token.  You'll want to store the token in another data store (Redis, a DB) or else use an extension like [Flask-KVSession](http://pythonhosted.org//Flask-KVSession/) to turn the session a server-side session.

Comment: Hmm. Ok. I would like to keep the access token out of a DB setup if possible, because I'm only using this to connect two specific accounts.

Comment: Is there any way to do this without using sessions or saving to a database? I'm only ever going to have one set of token + pub key.

Comment: Using sessions should be totally fine — by default the data are stored in a cookie (ie, they don't need a database), and they are totally secure.